# Why is CRM 2013 Online Plugin running under SYSTEM user all the time

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I've built a plugin for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 Online platform. The plugin is registered at Delete of my_custom_entity. It is synchronous and post-operational. Impersonation is set to Calling user. As far as I know the plugin should be fired with the calling user's privileges etc. with these settings.

I can't figure out why, but my the plugin is always run under "SYSTEM" user. I've tried to use two different system users with no luck whatsoever. It's kind of a problem because my plugin is calling a workflow and the workflow is sending an email. SYSTEM user can't send emails though.

Is this something new in CRM 2013? I tried to Google but couldn't find anything relevant. I already tried to unregister and register my plugin assembly again. No difference.

How can I change my plugin registration so that it would run on behalf of a user who fires the plugin (who deletes an entity).

Thank you

Comment: did you try to use an older plugin registration tool? I'm worried that can be a bug of the plugin registration you are using. If I have time I will set up a similar case with my online trial

Comment: @GuidoPreite Actually I just noticed some weird behavior in a plugin registration tool. It won't let me change the impersonation only but one time. When I restart the program then it lets me to do it again, but only once. I'll definitely try to get another version an give it a try. I'll let you know

Comment: Plugin registration tool I'm using now and facing a problem is version 6.1.1.1143 64bit. I have Windows 8 machine (plugin registration tool tells me Windows Version: Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0 64bit)

Comment: I've had problems with the plugin registration tool switching my changes with run as user as well. I switched back to version 6.1.0.519 and things started working again. If you have a dropbox account send me a mail and I'll share it with you.

Comment: I just downloaded 6.1.0.519 and it helped a bit. I'm now able to set Run as user to something else than "Calling user". If I do so everything works well. But still if I set "Run as" to Calling user my plugin fires as it would be SYSTEM user who triggered it. I don't recall having this problem earlier. Clearly there was a problem with the latest plugin registration tool though.

Comment: I made some debugging and proofed that when I choose a real user to "Run as" field my plugin is run on behalf of that user. But when I choose Calling user my plugin is run under SYSTEM user. This happens with 6.1.0.519 and 6.0.0000.0809 plugin registration tools (these two I tested).

Comment: @kivikall

Okay, I think that's something beyond the plugin registration tool. Take a look at the answer James Posted, I think he's on the right track.

Answer (score 4):

How are you obtaining your service reference?

If you do it like this you should get all the actions performed as the user who triggered the plugin.

```
// Obtain the organization service reference.
IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
```

If you are passing a null value you will get the system user, e.g. `serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService()`

[IOrganizationServiceFactory.CreateOrganizationService](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iorganizationservicefactory.createorganizationservice.aspx)

> Specifies the system user that calls to the service are made for. A
>   null value indicates the SYSTEM user. When called in a plug-in, a
>   Guid.Empty value indicates the same user as IPluginExecutionContext.
>   UserId. When called in a custom workflow activity, a Guid.Empty value
>   indicates the same user as IWorkflowExecutionContext.UserId. Any other
>   value indicates a specific system user.

Comment: I really hope I would have make a mistake there but no. I'm obtaining service reference just like you said with the context.UserId. Besides it wouldn't explain why it works with everything else than "Calling user" option?

Comment: Wow! I realized that it has something to do with Delete message / event. I tried to run another plugin that I have made exactly the same way basically but it had multiple steps, one registered on Create, another one on Update and one on Delete step. Create and Update steps works perfectly under the calling user but Delete step is executing under SYSTEM user even with this another plugin...

Answer (score 0):

YOu should use context.InitiatingUserId rather.

```
IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.InitiatingUserId);
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

The InitiatingUserId will be the user who triggers the delete action. In Delete context, UserId will be System where the platform is using.